# Multivariate repeated measures without between subject factors (Manova vs Anova)

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, manova

I'm trying to run an analysis in SPSS on some EEG data, obtained with the following design:

- 1 within subject factor,
- 6 dependent outcome variables.

First, I was thinking about a repeated measures ANOVA, however that wouldn't take into account the dependency of the outcome variables.
So, MANOVA? However, all documentation on MANOVA seems to include a between subjects factor (which I don't have).

Comment: Documentation you refer to are probably just case studies or examples. Of course, MANOVA does not require that between-factors be present.

Comment: +1 to @ttnphns. I have no idea how it is implemented in SPSS, but if you are familiar with a repeated measures ANOVA, then you know that it differs from standard ANOVA by further decomposing the within-group term: ANOVA decomposes the total sum of squares $\mathrm{SS}_t$ into between $\mathrm{SS}_b$ and within $\mathrm{SS}_w$ terms, whereas repeated measures ANOVA further decomposes $\mathrm{SS}_w$ into  $\mathrm{SS}_\mathrm{subjects}$ and $\mathrm{SS}_\mathrm{error}$. Exactly the same logic can be applied in MANOVA with sums of squares replaced by scatter matrices.